# Storing shareable embeded javascript for use later

Tags: javascript, embed

I came accross some embeded javascript, e.g.

```
<script src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym&deepLinkEmbedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym"></script>
```

I would like to know how I can execute this dynamically. The reason is, I would like to be able to save the code in a DB and then execute it on the fly later.

I've already tried using $.get with the url and doing an eval on the response with no luck.

I use jQuery if this helps with a solution.

How could I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: You should add an ooyala tag.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `$.getScript("http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym&deepLinkEmbedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym")`.

Note that if the script uses `document.write`, this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, this looks about right. It works, only trouble is I'm tring to get it to appear in a particular div. It appears at the bootom of my webpage. I've tried the following: $('#qwerty').append($.getScript("http... but it still appears at the bottom of my page. What am I missing?

Comment: @Haraldo: You need to check the script's documentation to find out how to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the entire string to the body using jquery

EDIT: have to escape some characters

```
$("body").append('\<script src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym&deepLinkEmbedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym"\>\<\/script\>');​
```

Comment: I just get an unterminated string literal using this. The issue starts at the first <script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `$.getScript("http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym&deepLinkEmbedCode=5oZDBoMzreLfI78xe1sCSLDmQQFyhXym&playerContainerId=myplayer")`

Note the `playerContainerId=myplayer` part.

Ooyala has a playerContainerId parameter if you want to add the player as innerHtml of a div and not a document.write().

http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/player_examples_qpass.html

Answer (score 0):

You could request it if it supported CORS and then use jQuery's `$.globalEval()` to evaluate the response - it is executed (from memory) within a `script` element.

Alternatively, remove the `script` element on load and then inject it when you want to use it again.